# CTRL+T hot key in Firefox missing suddenly

Tags: firefox, hotkeys

Okay, I am running FF 31 (just checked for updates, none) on Windows 8.1.

Overnight, the CTRL+T hot key in Firefox to open a new tab had disappeared.

I've installed nothing and run no updates to anything since yesterday.
If I right-click the tab bar, in the menu is an item for "New Tab", but it no longer has the hot key listed next to it.

Anyone know how to add back a hot key in Firefox?

Comment: Does it work to open another tab in a new tab you opened by the menu, without a page loaded in there? Some pages (most notably Twitter, lately) try to register this hotkey for something they like better than opening new tabs...

Comment: Huh! Yeah, you're right... in other tabs it does work, but not in Twitter's. Well that's annoying. I thought I'd tried it in various tabs... but okay; interesting. If you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if it works to open another tab in a new tab you opened by the menu, without a page loaded in there.

Some pages (most notably Twitter, lately) try to register this hotkey for something they like better than opening new tabs...